# blender file viewer takes very long to load files and folders

Tags: file-browser

Blender file viewer takes longer to load than usual, Also the file viewer is not letting choose geometry options, For whatever reason. Have checked other websites and such, The problem for all of them seems to only be the SD card reader, However, I'm not using any SD cards at all. Also, My blender version is 3.3.1, Is the version the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, The reason a specific file/folder takes longer than usual may be caused by:

Name that's used for blender to load in addons, settings, Plug-ins, etc, Those might cause an issue. If you made a folder name the same as Blender's default folder names, If there's no use such as using it as a directory, Just remove it after you're done.

Secondly, I've noticed that I have a lot of "dead" exe files, Which basically it's no longer installed, That might also cause blender to slow down, Remove the files/exe shortcuts if it's no longer useful.

Hope this help :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It took me like 3 to 4 years to understand why this was happening to me.

All the time when I install blender it works nice and smooth, but a few time later this problem comes back, every time I want to go to a specific folder, in my case “desktop” it will take like 10 seconds or more to wait, things that didn't happen on other folders. 10 second seems like a short amount of time, but when working on a project with multiple files to import an export, it is a pain.

But with the clues of the previous answer, I have understood what is going on.
The main cause of issue is network shortcuts, like for servers and other things that aren't on your computer, but you have file access to it thought a shortcut, this issue doesn't appear when you setup a new Windows OS configuration because you don't have access to these folders just after installation, but when you setup the network connection, is 100% sure that this problem will come up.

I've managed to move this shortcut network folders to another folder, “documents”, and the issue started to appear there, so this is the cause.

The thing that I did to “solve” was simply create a folder and moved the network shortcuts there, and it simply works.

[image]

**This where the folders Blender was having problem with**.

I hope it helps other people, best regards,

Ihnder

Comment: What version are you using? I used to experience lag on the desktop a lot and was happy to see this explanation, but now when I try to create network shortcuts 3.6.1 doesn't lag no matter what I do. maybe it's fixed.

Comment: Hello, 
I've been using this since 2.7x thought 3.6. This issue appeared, I can say, in “all” of them. I hope it fixed, on 3.6.0, isn't.