# Blender very slow to start up - some network problem

Tags: performance, windows, network

I'm trying to figure out why Blender is so slow to start on my Windows machine. I'm using version 4.0.1, but it was similar with previous versions too. The problem seems to be somehow network-dependent because when I switch off my wifi, it loads up in ~5 seconds. With the connection, it takes ~28 seconds. I suspect I have a problem similar to this one: [blender file viewer takes very long to load files and folders](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278671/blender-file-viewer-takes-very-long-to-load-files-and-folders), except for me it's happening on every Blender startup, not when opening files, and I have deleted all the network folder shortcuts I could find (yes, I had some in the past). I also tried running Blender with `--factory-startup` but that wasn't any faster, so it's not a problem with any of the addons.

I suspect Blender is checking something on the network, but I have no idea what and why. Any ideas how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I still had some network locations pinned in the Windows "Quick Access" menu. [Here's a page from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/pin-remove-and-customize-in-quick-access-7344ff13-bdf4-9f40-7f76-0b1092d2495b) on how to remove such items. After that, Blender starts in 5 seconds! yay!